# SQL generates empty table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I am joining three tables and generating a new table. However, the new table is empty. Below is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (WORD, TOTALCOUNT, AGENCYNAME) AS
SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY.TOTALCOUNT, AGENCY.AGENCYNAME
FROM NSFABSTRACTS LEFT JOIN DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY 
ON NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY.WORD
INNER JOIN AGENCY 
ON NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID=AGENCY.FILEID;
```

When I do not add the top line to create a table, the results look fine. But when I add the top line, it generates an empty table. Any thoughts why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of your inner join; I cannot say surely without looking at your data in the database. but try following;

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (WORD, TOTALCOUNT, AGENCYNAME) AS
SELECT NSFABSTRACTS.WORD, DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY.TOTALCOUNT, AGENCY.AGENCYNAME
FROM NSFABSTRACTS LEFT JOIN DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY 
ON NSFABSTRACTS.WORD=DOCUMENT_FREQUENCY.WORD
LEFT JOIN AGENCY 
ON NSFABSTRACTS.FILEID=AGENCY.FILEID;
```

Comment: So what if I just want a list of results that all tables share?

Comment: Just try what I have given here. If get NULL for some fields that means the problem with your inner join

Comment: I do get a lot of NULL cells, and I do not want them.